# pyspark : Convert DataFrame to RDD[string]

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to convert `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` to `pyspark.rdd.RDD[String]`

I converted a DataFrame `df` to RDD `data`:

```
data = df.rdd
type (data)
## pyspark.rdd.RDD
```

the new RDD `data` contains `Row`

```
first = data.first()
type(first)
## pyspark.sql.types.Row

data.first()
Row(_c0=u'aaa', _c1=u'bbb', _c2=u'ccc', _c3=u'ddd')
```

I'd like to convert `Row` to list of `String` , like example below:

```
u'aaa',u'bbb',u'ccc',u'ddd'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

PySpark `Row` is just a `tuple` and can be used as such. All you need here is a simple `map` (or `flatMap` if you want to flatten the rows as well) with `list`:

```
data.map(list)
```

or if you expect different types:

```
data.map(lambda row: [str(c) for c in row])
```

Comment: Thanks @zero323 with your answers my learning curve going better

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is old.  With Spark 2.0, you must now explicitly state that you're converting to an rdd by adding `.rdd` to the statement.  Therefore, the equivalent of this statement in Spark 1.0:

```
data.map(list)
```

Should now be:

```
data.rdd.map(list)
```

in Spark 2.0.
Related to the accepted answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535447/attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-map).