# What is PySpark SQL equivalent function for pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.to_string?

Tags: pyspark

Pandas API function: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html

Another answer, though it doesn't work for me [pyspark : Convert DataFrame to RDD[string]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35457927/pyspark-convert-dataframe-to-rddstring)

Following above post advice, I tried going with

```
data.rdd.map(lambda row: [str(c) for c in row])
```

Then I get this error

```
TypeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable
```

I would like for it to output rows of strings as if it's similar to `to_string()` above. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Would [pyspark.sql.DataFrame.show](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.show.html) satisfy your expectations about the console output? You can sort the df via [pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sort](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sort.html) before printing if required.

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: There seems to be no direct method on pyspark SQL dataframes to extract the string output format you are looking for. However, a simple `print(data.pandas_api().to_string())` does the job (in your desired format), since pandas-on-Spark DataFrames and Spark DataFrames are virtually interchangeable (see the [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/pandas_pyspark.html). I see no benefit in trying to somehow convert the data to low-level rdd's instead of sticking to high-level API's.

Comment: Does this solve your issue @user10443249 ? If so, please mark the answer as useful